# Implementing ForEach.onMove() with Core Data

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I am trying to implement `ForEach.onMove` using Core Data. I have two entities, `Parent` with a To-Many relationship to `Child`, with the relationship marked as Ordered. The view is something like this:

```
struct ParentView : View {
  @ObservedObject var parent : Parent

  var body : some View {
    List {
      ForEach($parent.children! as! [Child]) { child in 
        ChildView(child)
      }.onMove { 
        parent.managedObjectContext!.performAndWait { indices, to in
          (parent.children! as! NSMutableOrderedSet).moveObjects(at: indices, to: to)
          try! parent.managedObjectContext!.save()
          parent.objectWillChange.send()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results are:

1. No errors of any kind.
2. During debug of the `onMove` function, I can see that the items are re-ordered as required
3. The `managedObjectContext.updatedObjects` is empty at the same debug step, before the call to `save()`
4. When reloading the app, the re-ordering is obviously not saved (apparently because the `updatedObjects` set was empty at #3.)

What am I doing wrong? How can I make the MOC realize the re-ordering change?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this, apparently with a simple solution. I am posting this for future generations of google searchers. :D

The problem is with this line:

```
(parent.children! as! NSMutableOrderedSet).moveObjects(at: indices, to: to)
```

Apparently, taking the immutable version and making it mutable works, but doesn't update the managed object. This works:

```
parent.mutableOrderedSetValue(forKey: "children").moveObjects(at: indices, to: to)
```